# Mistakes in Native Language

Tags: linguistic-typology, comparative-linguistics

I was wondering if there is some research on the number of mistakes made by native speakers in certain languages? I think that since some languages are more complex (their grammar is more complex) and some are less it can be that native speakers of complex languages make more mistakes in their speaking and writing.

My native language is Russian, and I also speak English and French fluently. I see that average Russian people often make mistakes (wrong declension, wrong stress, wrong punctuation). And as I can see English and French people make less mistakes.

I think linguists should introduce some kind of an index of mistakes made by native speakers to measure complexity of a language.

Comment: Technically, native speakers can't make "mistakes" in their native languages.

Comment: I think that would be harder to do than it sounds, and the results would be very much open to interpretation. For one thing you have the problem of whether what you're looking at is a mistake or just a non-standard usage (*are you paying for those separate?*), then you have the problem of whether more mistakes really do indicate greater complexity or whether they indicate that the grammar is less intuitive, that speakers have a lower level of education, that they are less concerned about speaking "properly" etc. Also, don't forget...

Comment: ... that you are much more sensitive to mistakes (or just things you wouldn't say yourself) in your own language than in foreign languages. There are a few (minor) errors in your post, but obviously you haven't noticed them. I'm sure you would have done if you were reading something posted in Russian by a non-native speaker.

Comment: @ErgativeMan In theory, you are right. By definition, a native speaker (like an automaton) defines usage of a language. But in practice, we have a notion of illiteracy, deviation from the literary norm of a language.

Comment: @ConstantinWerner , a literary form is a mere convention created from a notable dialect, it is not a "real" thing. So, every variant ofa language is equally important and has its own features that diverge from the artificial/old standard rules.

Comment: Yes but everybody breaks the rules of their personal variant from time to time - we misspeak, we make slips...

Comment: @ergativeman, wikipedia has an entry on error as made by foreign speakers out of ignorance in contradistinction to mistakes as made by native speakers due to momentary laps of reason, for lack of a better word; the topic was second language learning. The terminology is apparently not universally accepted as it seems (like most termini in linguistics, lol), but it's quite useful to keep in mind.

Comment: @ConstantinWerner, I don't know the answer, but it seems obvious that this has to be asked in conjunction with the error-tolerance of the language, more as s function of social predicates perhaps. This can be cause and reason at the same time. Anyhow, your perception of error-rates in English is heavily biased because you are obviously not a native speaker, no offence, (perhaps an internet native though). Studiey to that effect surely exist variously about individual details, but you might want a summary, which is unlikely to be found if general complexity is not a well defined.

Comment: Cororally, I find a lot of native English quite tasteless; proper English an ideal that does not exist as such in native speech, while higher registers with a claim for correctness are an acquired taste. There are more factors than just correctness at play. After all, if I say nothing I can thus avoid making mistakes, ... so i'll du just that

Comment: @ErgativeMan Of course native speakers can make mistakes. Spoonerisms, slips of the tongue, Freudian slips, thinking about something else and accidentally producing a meaningless mixture of what you meant to say and what you were thinking about – those are all mistakes in speech and all perfectly common in native speakers. Even things like declension and conjugation can go awry in natural speech. There’s a difference between your native grammar diverging from a formalised standard, and accidentally slipping up and producing something that’s ungrammatical even to you.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet , yes, this kind of mistakes do happen, I was talking about "deviations from a standardized language's grammar" kind of mistakes, like ending sentences with propositions in english etc:)

Comment: The mistake is assuming everybody has the same grammar. One man's mistake is another one's norm. The concept of "mistake" means "not talking like I expect you to", where everybody has their own opinion of what's correct to say in any context. At least you get the impression they think they do.

Answer (score 1):

There is research by Jürgen Meisel on this topic, specially in the context of language acquisition by children. The main takeaway is that the kind of errors made by native language learners are different from the kind of errors made by second language learners.

Also note, that linguistically, spoken language is the gold standard. Mastering a written language that has a considerable distance to the spoken language is something very different. And it is "second language" to everyone, there are no "native writers" in a linguistic sense.